# .htaccess RewriteRule to remove string between

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to find a RewriteRule that will redirect from http://website.cz/uploads/fotky/test---4751_image2.jpg to http://website.cz/uploads/fotky/4751_image2.jpg.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(uploads/fotky)/test--(.+)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... i was trying to set there any regual expressions, with strange results...

Thanks to you - i found the solution with variable instead of test---
`code`RewriteRule ^(uploads/fotky)/(?<=fotky\/)(.*\n?)(?<=---)(.+)$ /$1/$3 [L,NC,R=301]`code`

Thanks

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.